# How do I do a batch operation with RIA?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

Most of the operations in my silverlight client are things that add/update/insert/delete multiple entities in one go.

E.g:
`CreateStandardCustomer` adds a `Customer`, `Address`, `Person` and `Contract` record.
`CreateEnterpriseCustomer` adds a `Customer`, `Address`, 2x `Person` and a `CreditLimit` record.

It looks like with a DomainService you can only do one thing at a time, e.g. add a customer record, add an address etc. **How can I do a batch operation?**

You might say to simply add the relevant records from the Silverlight client and call the `SubmitChanges()` method. However this is difficult to validate against (server side) because only certain groups of records can be added/update/deleted at a time. E.g. in the example above, an `Address` record added alone would not be valid in this system.

Another example would be something like `Renew` which updates a `Customer` record and adds a `Renewal`. These operations aren't valid individually.

Thanks for your help,
Kurren

**EDIT**: The server side validation needs to check that the correct operations in the batch has taken place. E.g. From the example above we `Renew` then a `Renewal` should be created and a `Customer` should have been updated (one without the other is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but you update a batch of entities the same way you do individual entities: namely perform all the operations on your context and then call SubmitChanges on that context. At the server your insert/delete/update methods for the types will be called as appropriate for all the changes you're submitting.

We use RIA/EF in Silverlight to do exactly that. It doesn't matter if you just create a single entity in your client context (complete with graph) or 100, because as soon as you submit those changes the complete changeset for that context is operated upon.

EDIT: Failing setting up your entity metadata with `Required` and `Composition` attributes on the appropriate properties, you can also use the DomainService.ChangeSet object to inspect what has been submitted and make decisions on what changes you want to accept or not.

Comment: But I need to validate that only certain groups of entities were submitted at a time. E.g. I don't want the client simply adding an Address and calling SubmitChanges, the address needs to be added along with other entities depending on the operation (see example above).

Comment: If you've defined your entity metadata correctly you'll get validation errors if someone tries to submit an entity that isn't 'complete'. E.g. if Address is a Required field of Customer, and that it is compositional (i.e. can only be created as part of a composition) then you won't be able to submit an address on its own. I'd also make it so that my UI didn't allow such things, by only having a 'create address' screen accessible from a customer screen ... and then you know which customer this is an address for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if the entities in the group have no association to each other, or if the operation includes update/delete? E.g. From the example above, Renew updates a Customer and also adds a Renewal record (one shouldn't be allowed without the other). These operations need to validated as a batch, not just individually.

Also, with the UI, the user can easily set up a fake RIA services client and interact with the service from there.

Comment: For our domain service we predominantly rely on the naming convention for data operations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373(v=vs.91).aspx : conventions). This means if there is a whole batch of insert/update/deletes for entities then the appropriate methods will be used based on those conventions. We do not have to intervene or decide on what operation is taking place on what entity. You can also call specific methods from those methods, if you so desire, so you could manually call an 'update renewal' from the `UpdateCustomer` method or a 'create renewal' from  `InsertCustomer`